# Extract column of header from a given file

Tags: java, header-files, bufferedreader

I'm trying to extract the columns names from a given file using java.

Example file content:

```
person_id,person_name
 100        Alice
 250        Louis
```

The content file like a csv format.
My code is the following:

```
protected Map<String, String> fileHeader(FileProvider fs, String file, HashMap<String, Object> metaData) {
        Map<String, String> fixedFormatProperties = new HashMap<String,String>();
        
        //fixedFormatProperties.put(FixedFormat.COLUMN_SEPARATOR__PARAM, columnSep);
        
        
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            br.close();
            
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                final String[] lineValues = line.split(",");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return null;
    }
```

My solution read all lines, but what I'm looking is to extract only the columns names from any given file that have the format and the content as the example above ? And how can I return a `Map<String, String>` as result ?
Thank you

Comment: If headers are always the first line, then you can stop after reading the first line, isn't it? Then what is the motivation behind using `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)`?

Comment: yes the headers are always the first line

Comment: how can I stop reading after the first line ?

Comment: if you only want to read one line, then do not use a while loop to process all lines ... just do a ``br.readLine()`` to read the first line, followed by a ``line.split()`` to process that line.

Comment: You open the file and then close it right away. How do you expect to read data from a closed file?